# Serialize vertx JsonObject using Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, vert.x

I'm using **vertx** and **Jackson** in my development. In one of my classes, I got a field of type `JsonObject`, something like this:

```
class User
  private String name;
  private JsonObject details;
```

This *details* field can contain other JsonObjects or JsonArrays, e.g.:
`{"details": [{"street": "Broadway"}, {"building": 20}]}`
I don't have a dedicated class of this structure, as far as there's no fixed structure and it can vary.
*details* object is being created in the way like this:

```
JsonObject details = new JsonObject().put("name", "value").put("another", "another")
```

This aproach allows me to store details of any structure inside my code. As far as I don't need to manipulate this data on my backend, I don't want to create a special structure for it.
Everything works fine until I'm trying to serialize this `JsonObject` using **Jackson**. Unfortunately, instead of beatiful JSON string, Jackson gives me `map` object serialized with all map's additional fields.

How can I serialize `JsonObject` of **vertx** using **Jackson**?

Comment: You can use the Jackson's JsonNode instead of JsonObject.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need `JsonObject`. There's a lot of code dependent on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it turned out that **vertx** already has it's own implementation of Serializer.
It's enough just to use theirs class to perform serialization (which will use Jackson undercover).

```
JsonObject user = new JsonObject(Json.encode(new User());
```

And it works fine.

Comment: That looks very inefficient: This serializes the User object to JSON, then deserializes (when the JsonObject constructor is called), then re-serializes (once you serialize the JsonObject to send it over the wire).

Comment: To go from `User` to `JsonObject` without the intermediate String, use [JsonObject.mapFrom](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/json/JsonObject.html#mapFrom-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: That should be the real answer !

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [JsonObject's javadoc](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/json/JsonObject.html) , I saw a [`getMap()`](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/json/JsonObject.html#getMap--) method.  I know Jackson is capable of serializing Maps with ease.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating using  https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.7.3/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class) like this: 

`new JsonObject((Map)Json.mapper.convertValue(new User(), Map.class));`

Converting to and from `String` takes time.